# Kubernetes Statefulsets: Restart all pods concurrently (instead of in sequence)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I have a use-case for concurrent restart of all pods in a statefulset.

Does kubernetes statefulset support concurrent  restart of all pods?

According to the statefulset documentation, this can be accomplished by setting the pod update policy to parallel as in this example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mysql-db
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  replicas: 3
```

However this does not seem to work in practice, as demonstrated on this statefulset running on EKS:

- Apply this:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: producer
  namespace: ragnarok
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: producer
  replicas: 10
  podManagementPolicy: "Parallel"
  serviceName: producer-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: producer
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: producer
        image: archbungle/load-tester:pulsar-0.0.49
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Rollout restart happens in sequence as if disregarding the rollout policy setting:

```
(base) welcome@Traianos-MacBook-Pro eks-deploy % kubectl get pods -n ragnarok | egrep producer
producer-0                               1/1     Running             0          3m58s
producer-1                               1/1     Running             0          3m56s
producer-2                               1/1     Running             0          3m53s
producer-3                               1/1     Running             0          3m47s
producer-4                               1/1     Running             0          3m45s
producer-5                               1/1     Running             0          3m43s
producer-6                               1/1     Running             1          3m34s
producer-7                               0/1     ContainerCreating   0          1s
producer-8                               1/1     Running             0          16s
producer-9                               1/1     Running             0          19s

(base) welcome@Traianos-MacBook-Pro eks-deploy % kubectl get pods -n ragnarok | egrep producer
producer-0                               1/1     Running       0          4m2s
producer-1                               1/1     Running       0          4m
producer-2                               1/1     Running       0          3m57s
producer-3                               1/1     Running       0          3m51s
producer-4                               1/1     Running       0          3m49s
producer-5                               1/1     Running       0          3m47s
producer-6                               0/1     Terminating   1          3m38s
producer-7                               1/1     Running       0          5s
producer-8                               1/1     Running       0          20s
producer-9                               1/1     Running       0          23s

(base) welcome@Traianos-MacBook-Pro eks-deploy % kubectl get pods -n ragnarok | egrep producer
producer-0                               1/1     Running       0          4m8s
producer-1                               1/1     Running       0          4m6s
producer-2                               1/1     Running       0          4m3s
producer-3                               1/1     Running       0          3m57s
producer-4                               1/1     Running       0          3m55s
producer-5                               0/1     Terminating   0          3m53s
producer-6                               1/1     Running       0          4s
producer-7                               1/1     Running       0          11s
producer-8                               1/1     Running       0          26s
producer-9                               1/1     Running       0          29s
```

Comment: `kubectl -n  ragnarok delete po -l app=producer` will do that, if I understand your question correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the document pointed, Parallel pod management will effective only in the scaling operations. `This option only affects the behavior for scaling operations. Updates are not affected.`

Maybe you can try something like
`kubectl scale statefulset producer --replicas=0 -n ragnarok`
and
`kubectl scale statefulset producer --replicas=10 -n ragnarok`

According to documentation, all pods should be deleted and created together by scaling them with the Parallel policy.

Reference : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#parallel-pod-management